# Exposing webform submissions for Views, but not giving anonymous users permission to view all submissions

Tags: views, 8, webforms

I have a webform set up in Drupal 8 and am trying to create a View that displays certain fields from form submissions. The webform and the view seem to be set up fine and are working.

The problem comes in when I want the view to be visible for anonymous users. I seem to be stuck with two options, neither of which are ideal:

- Option 1: Anonymous users can see the page created in Views, but there are no fields on it.
- Option 2: Anonymous users can see the page with the fields, but I have to grant the "View any webform submissions" permission, which then gives them access to view (and download) on the webform page itself.

Can anyone help me with an option 3, where the fields are visible in this View, but without granting the "View any webform submissions" permission to anonymous users?

Comment: I have the same issue - webform submissions cannot be exposed via Views without providing full access to trawl al submissions and download them. It's been explored here: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2965814

Answer (score -1):

You will have to give following permissions to anonymous users from permissions page. admin/people/permissions

View any webform submissions

Allows viewing all webforms and submissions.

Comment: This permission is the same one that exposes the 'results' tab the OP wants to avoid, plus it is also a very broad permissions to assign to anonymous users. What if you also have forms collecting sensitive personal data?